# How to export all the dependent DLL files automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dependencies

I used C# to write a program in .NET Framework 3.5.

But when I finished that and moved it to another computer on which .NET Framework 3.5 was installed, the program couldn't be started. It missed some dependent DLL files.

But when I moved this program to a computer that had Visual Studio 2008 installed, it ran perfectly.

So what can I do to export all the dependent DLL files automatically? So my program can run on a computer without installing Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you just need to include the third party component that your project use.

Edit:

To know them you need go to references and check the Added DLL.

Edit2:

Did you try to make a setup for your project it will automatically collect all the library used in your applications?

another point is, are you using win32 libraries, if yes also you should include them?

Comment: yeah I have done this and set copyToLocal = true, but still not work

Comment: No messages, just run in background and can't pop the UI dialog

Comment: What is the win32 libraries ?

Comment: Win32 contains native code not like dotnet assembly contains MSIL, Win32 lib or exe  produced by C++ or delphi or vb6 etc...

Comment: I have included all of them, but still not work and have no prompt messages.

Comment: In the main form Load for your application try to make log file that store every code line after executing it, and see where is it crashes.